# Web parsing | How to get data that's generated by script

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I want to parse site, and I want to get a data which is generated by script. To get this data I have to run next js script in chrome dev tools console

```
let key;

grecaptcha
  .execute(<SITE_KEY>, { action: 'pageview' })
  .then(function(e) {
    $.post('/recaptcha', {
      token: e,
      imprints: key
    }).done(function(i) {
      console.log(i);
    });
  });
```

Problem is next, key it's a *data-verify* attribute in span (see screenshoot below)
[image: s]

I have python script that parse page and get all keys for all objects i need, but problem that when I run that script all keys are different with keys from page (because page reloaded probably, or different cookies). I need any ideas how to run this script properly. And let me know if you need any info to clarify smth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I did it with Selenium WebDriver, it can execute javascript code in python via `execute_script` method.